# Need to access static property of class without adding a DLL dependency

Tags: c#, .net, class, inline

I have a class inside a DLL (`Database.dll`) which has a static property:

```
public class Database
{
    public static int[] ReleasedDatabaseVersions
    {
        get { return new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 }; }
    }
}
```

I have created a standalone executable (`ValidateInstall.exe`) which needs to access `ReleasedDatabaseVersions` in the `Database` class.

However, I want `ValidateInstall.exe` to be entirely independent of `Database.dll` (i.e. I want to be able to run it on a PC without this DLL installed).

In C++ inlining would make this very easy.  Is this possible in C#?

I don't want to repeat this data in my executable as this would be a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) post-build to embed the assembly holding the `Database` class into your exe:

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET
>   assemblies into a single assembly.

The ILMerge page also links to an [article by Jeffrey Richter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx), detailing how to achieve something similar *without* using ILMerge.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me.  I ended up creating a shared DLL as suggested by @Corey and then using `ILMerge` to combine this shared DLL with the executable.  This removed any run-time dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The only cases I know of where items from some project B are inlined into some other project A are consts and enums. It seems to me that the .NET-ish way of solving your problem is to factor ReleasedDatabaseVersions out into a third project. This third project would then be referenced by both ValidateInstall.exe and Database.dll

Answer (score 0):

You can add the source code for the `Database` class as a link to your standalone project so both projects share a single source code file.

When using "Add Existing Item..." choose "Add as Link" rather than the standard Add.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the reference and including the references to the built executable would be a way to ensure that the program runs on systems which don't have the DLL installed by including it in the build.

I can't really think of any way to distribute this application without actually duplicating the DLL or the Static content

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at using DllImport attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=VS.71).aspx

**UPDATED**
If you don't want to use this method of late binding, there is always the Assembly class.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("Database.dll"); // This will throw an error that you can catch if the file does not exist.
Database d = a.CreateInstance("Database") as Database;
```

Now, I am not sure if the reflection will bring in all of the functions or not. I have not used this method before, so I couldn't give you a correct solution.

Comment: Is this at all relevant to the question?

Comment: Well, this is on way to achieve late binding to a dll file.

Comment: Yes, and the OP explicitly stated that they don't want to do that: *"I want `ValidateInstall.exe` to be entirely independent of `Database.dll` (i.e. I want to be able to run it on a PC without this DLL installed"*.

Comment: Wizetux noted that Assembly.LoadFrom() will throw an exception which can be caught if the file does not exist.  You could also check to see if the file exists before attempting to load it.  Edit: Although it will need to be changed from Database d = ... to Object d = ..., and Reflection will be needed to access members.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Correct, you can and **should** do that, but the Assembly.LoadFrom() is the only way that the OP would be able to load the assembly during runtime without requiring the assembly to actually be found or on the system to get the exe to run at all.